# How this AWK is replacing an IF?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, gawk

I've reviewing some bash scripts written by other people at work and I found this line that I'm trying to understand

```
[[ $(awk 'BEGIN{print ('$CAPACITY'>=0.9)}') -eq 1 ]] && echo "Capacity at 90 Percent"
```

Is my understanding that this line is replacing an if statement. Could someone help me out explaining what this line really does. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This makes me very sad and pessimistic about the future of civilization...

Let's break this down:

```
[[ $(awk 'BEGIN{print ('$CAPACITY'>=0.9)}') -eq 1 ]] && echo "Capacity at 90 Percent"
```

Note the `$(....)`. This tells the shell to execute the program inside, and replace the contents of `$(...)` with the value. For example:

```
$ file_name="/usr/local/bin/foo"
$ short_name="$(basename $file_name)"
$ echo $short_name
foo
```

In this the second line, we are running the command `basename $file_name`. This returns `foo`. Then, the shell will substitute `foo` for `$(basename $filename)` before assigning `short_name`. Here's the same thing with the debugger on:

```
$ set -xv
$ file_name="/usr/local/bin/foo"
foo=/usr/local/bin/foo
+ foo=/usr/local/bin/foo
$ short_name=$(basename $file_name)
short_name=$(basename $file_name)
basename $file_name
++ basename /usr/local/bin/foo
+ short_name=foo
$ echo $short_name
echo $short_name
+ echo foo
foo
$ set +xv   # Turn off the debugger.
```

You can see how the shell executes `$(...)` and replaces it.

Thus, the user is actually running the program:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print ('$CAPACITY'>=0.9)}'
```

However, take a look at the quotation marks:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print ('$CAPACITY'>=0.9)}'
     +++++++++++++           +++++++
```

The stuff with the pluses under it are part of the `awk` command inside single quotes and thus cannot be interpolated by the shell. HOWEVER, `$CAPACITY` is not in quotes. In other words, the value of `$CAPACITY` replaces that variable before the `awk` command is executed. Thus, if `$CAPACITY` is .8, the `awk` command will become:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print ('.8'>=0.9)}`
```

That's the very first part of the explanation.

Now on to the next part. How much do you know about `awk`?

Awk is a programming language that's usually part of Unix/Linux distributions. Awk normally works on files and assumes a loop around the file with each line being read in and operated on. For example:

```
$ awk '{print $1}` foo.txt
```

Let's assume that each line in `foo.txt` consists of several fields that are separated by spaces. The file `foo.txt` is read in and each line is passed through to the `awk` program and the `awk` program will print out the first field of each line.

However, there is no file for `awk` to operate on. This developer is using the special patter `BEGIN`. This is executed before any lines are read in. Since there is no file for `awk` to process, and there is no actual `awk` program (only a BEGIN statement), `awk` will execute this statement (assuming capacity is at 80%:

```
.8 >= .9
```

Like in Shell and other programming languages. This statement will evaluate as true or false. In `awk`, if this statement is true, it will a non-zero value (we hope `1`). If it is false, it will equal zero. In this case, it will equal false.

Awk returns (like Perl) the last value it executes. Thus, if the capacity is at 80%, the `awk` statement `.8 >= .9` will be false. Awk will return a zero.

Now, the entire `$([[ $(awk 'BEGIN{print ('$CAPACITY'>=0.9)}')` will be replaced with `0`. Your `[[ ... ]]` test now becomes:

[[ 0 -eq 1 ]] && echo "Capacity at 90 Percent"

Well, `[[ 0 -eq 1 ]]` is false.

Now the final part.

The two *commands* `&&` and `||` are list operators. Their name comes from the C programming operators of the same name, and the way C short circuits tests. For example,

```
if ( ( bar > 20 ) && ( foo < 30 ) ) {
```

is a typical C if statement. with `foo` and `bar` being variables. I am asking if bar is greater than 20 *AND* if foo is less than 30 to do something.

C will first evaluate `bar > 20` and decide whether it is true or false. If `bar > 20` is false, there's is no need to test `foo < 30` because no matter what the results are, the statement is still false. What if `bar` is indeed greater than 20? You have to run the next part of the `if` statement.

Imagine this:

```
if ( ( bar > 20 ) || ( foo < 30 ) ) {
```

This says if `bar` is greater than 20 *OR* `foo` < 30. In this case, C will evaluate whether `bar` is greater than 20. If it is, there is no need to test whether or not `foo` is less than 30. The statement will be true no matter what the value of `foo` is. What if `bar` isn't greater than 20? Then, I have to test the value of `foo`.

So, if I have `&&` and the first statement is false, don't do the second statement (the entire expression is false anyway). If the first statement is true, I have to run the second statement (because I don't know whether or not that entire statement is true or not).

If I have `||`, the complete opposite happens. If the first statement is true, don't do the second statement (because the entire expression is true). If that first statement is false, I have to run the second statement.

The gist of this is:

```
[ "$foo" = "$bar" ] && echo "Foo equals bar"
```

is the same as:

```
if [ "$foo" = "$bar" ]
then
    echo "Foo equals bar"
fi
```

Because if `$foo` does equal `$bar`, I have to execute the second part of the statement!

And, this:

```
[ "$foo" = "$bar" ] || echo "Foo and Bar are not equal"
```

is the same as:

```
if [ "$foo" != "$bar" ]
then
    echo "Foo and Bar are not equal"
fi
```

---

1. So, first the shell substitutes in the value of the shell variable `$CAPACITY` into your little `awk` script.
2. Next the `awk` script runs testing whether or not the substituted value of `$CAPACITY` is greater than or equal to 0.9. Since there is no actual `awk` program, `awk` doesn't attempt to read in from STDIN.
3. Next, awk will assign a zero or non-zero value to that *boolean* statement (depending whether or not it's true). Then, the `awk` program will exit with the evaluated value of that boolean statement.
4. The shell now substitutes that zero or non-zero value for that entire `$(...)` phrase. This is run through a test to see if it is or isn't equal to 1.
5. Finally if that test statement is equal to 1, the `&&` will tell the shell to *evaluate* that `echo` statement. Thus, if the shell variable `$CAPACITY` is .9 or greater, that `echo` statement will print.

---

That's a lot of machinations just to compare `.8` (or whatever the capacity is) with `.9`, so why did the developer do this?

Probably because BASH shell can only do integer arithmetic. Since `$CAPACITY` is less than one, you can't do this:

```
if [[ $CAPACITY -le .9 ]]
then
    echo "Capacity is at 90%"
fi
```

Instead of using awk,  I would probably have used [bc](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bc):

```
OVER_CAPACITY=$(bc <<<"$CAPACITY >= .9")
if [[ ! $OVER_CAPACITY -eq $(true) ]]
then
    echo "Capacity is over 90%"
else
    echo "Every thing is okay"
fi
```

It would have been a few more lines, but I hope it makes things a bit easier to understand and make the file easier to maintain.

Comment: While technically correct, and well stated, I honestly think this may only help add to the OPs confusion on the topic.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The complete line can be thought of as `[[ if something is true ]] &&=then do another thing`

To understand what is going on in this code, turn on your mental shell parser, and find the innermost construct that will produce output. in this case

```
 awk 'BEGIN{print ('$CAPACITY'>=0.9)}'
```

execute that on a cmd-line by itself. Obviously the variable CAPACITY has to be set with a value.

Then you can use the shell debug/trace facility (`set -vx`) to see every thing executing

```
CAPACITY=0.95
set -vx
[[ $(awk 'BEGIN{print ('$CAPACITY'>=0.9)}') -eq 1 ]] && echo "Capacity at 90 Percent"
+ awk 'BEGIN{print (0.95>=0.9)}'
+ [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]
+ echo 'Capacity at 90 Percent'
Capacity at 90 Percent
```

IHTH

Comment: No, `[[ ... ]]` is not replacing "if". The "if" functionality comes from the `&&`, which means "only execute the next command *if* the previous one succeeded". The `[[ ... ]]` is the part that is the condition that the "if" tests...

Answer (score 1):

It's not, the `[[` and `]]` are an improvement upon the *test* builtin and the `&&` is an *AND*

So, what this line is doing equivalent to:

```
if [[ $(awk 'BEGIN{print ('$CAPACITY'>=0.9)}') -eq 1 ]] ; then
    echo "Capacity at 90 Percent"
fi
```

In effect, the line is saying **TEST this condition AND do this other thing only if it's TRUE**

Similarly, you could do `[[ something_to_test ]] || do this if something_to_test is false`

which means, **TEST this condition OR do this other thing**

These are `bash shell` one-line shortcuts.

Comment: Documented in the manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists

Comment: The `[[ ... ]]` are ***not*** synonyms for `test` (builtin or otherwise). `[ ... ]` is the true synonym and as such, has all the shortfalls found with `test`. The `[[ ... ]]` was created to get around these shortfalls found in `[ ... ]` where the shell interpolation can cause problems.

Comment: They are indeed synonyms for `test` in the `bash` shell (and it's derivatives), but sure, `[ ... ]` was the original syntax in `bourne` shell, and was improved upon by `bash`.  That doesn't really help the OP much, though, does it?

Comment: @Donovan David is correct. `[[` is quite distinct from `[`/`test` and *not* a synonym, providing strictly more functionality than the `test` command.

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify and end this debate. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You got a lot of good explanations, now rewrite the whole thing as:

```
awk -v cap="$CAPACITY" 'BEGIN{ if (cap>=0.9) print "Capacity at 90 Percent" }'
```

for clarity and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

[[ .... ]] construct returns true or false.
so the exp in [[ .... ]] must be a logic operation